# Discontinuities of $\sum \frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

H. Edwards in his book on the zeta function says that $\sum\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}$ converges conditionally "even when $\rho ,1-\rho$ are paired." I tried calculating some terms (n = 500 or so) and noticed the result below. Could be bad programming on my part or an aspect of the calculation for low numbers.

The expressions below assume RH but I am asking about the calculation for small finite n. It may be that an answer has to assume RH.

$$\sum \frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho} = \sum_n \frac{x^{\rho_n}}{\rho_n}+\frac{x^{1-\rho_n}}{1-\rho_n}$$

seems to be zero or (to be piecewise continuous and) have discontinuities at x = prime. And like (for example) square wave Fourier approximations there is a noticeable Gibbs-like effect near these discontinuities.

$\rho_n$ are non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function. I should add the possibility that what appears to be prime may be nearly prime.

I checked through $x = 100.$ 83 seemed doubtful until I used a better approximation and 97 seems to require more summands than I have time to calculate. Primes are *not* the only such points. The expression appears to show the same behavior for a lot of composites (4 is one) less than 20 but fewer as x grows.

Can anyone explain why this would be so? Thank you.

FWIW as a check on my work I think that the expression below in which $\alpha_{n}$ are imaginary part of $\rho_n$ is equivalent and (like the 2d one above) assumes RH. It seems to give the same approximation as the second expression above.

$$\sum_{\zeta(\rho)=0}\frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho} = \sqrt{x}\cdot\sum_{n =1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\alpha_{n}\ln x)+2\alpha_{n}\sin(\alpha_{n}\ln x)}{1/4+\alpha_{n}^2}\hspace{5mm}$$

Comment: The first sum is only conditionally convergent and in a "principal value" sense, it seems in the second sum you are trying to overcome this by pairing the zeros up with there neighbors? Also the sum is not zero, when x is a prime.

Comment: Yes, according to Edwards they converge only conditionally even when paired. The increasing order of Im$|\rho|$ is crucial. That said...

Comment: How are you even calculating the zeros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to be expected, given the [explicit formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExplicitFormula.html). This series does not give us the prime counting function directly (where we would expect discontinuities at primes but not composites), but rather a "reweighted" prime counting function, the $2$nd Chebyshev function. We have

$$\psi(x)=\sum_{p^v\le x}\log p=x-\left(\sum_\rho\frac{x^\rho}{\rho}\right)-\log(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right).$$

Clearly $\psi(x)$ should be expected to have discontinuities not just at primes but all prime powers, like the example $x=4=2^2$ you found, and none of the other quantities on the right side, $x$, $\log(2\pi)$, or $\log(1-x^{-2})$ will have discontinuities on the positive reals $>2$.

Comment: When you remind me that this expression equals the Chebyshev function it is clear. Thank you!